How to resolve the issue of importing external modules in Rust?
I encountered the following problem while doing the exercises.I want to know how to pass the test. I don't understand the meaning of this exercise and I don't know how to solve it.
// tests9.rs
// 
// Rust is highly capable of sharing FFI interfaces with C/C++ and other statically compiled
// languages, and it can even link within the code itself! It makes it through the extern // block, just like the code below.
// 
// The short string after the `extern`keyword indicates which ABI the externally imported 
// function would follow. In this exercise, "Rust" is used, while other variants exists like 
// "C" for standard C ABI, "stdcall" for the Windows ABI. 
// 
// The externally imported functions are declared in the extern blocks, with a semicolon to 
// mark the end of signature instead of curly braces. Some attributes can be applied to those 
// function declarations to modify the linking behavior, such as #[link_name = ".."] to // modify the actual symbol names. 
// 
// If you want to export your symbol to the linking environment, the`extern`keyword can 
// also be marked before a function definition with the same ABI string note. The default ABI 
// for Rust functions is literally "Rust", so if you want to link against pure Rust functions, 
// the whole extern term can be omitted. 
// 
// Rust mangles symbols by default, just like C++ does. To suppress this behavior and make 
// those functions addressable by name, the attribute #[no_mangle] can be applied. 
// 
// In this exercise, your task is to make the testcase able to call the`my_demo_function`in 
// module Foo. the`my_demo_function_alias`is an alias for`my_demo_function`, so the two
// line of code in the testcase should call the same function.
//
// You should NOT modify any existing code except for adding two lines of attributes.

// I AM NOT DONE

extern "Rust" {
    fn my_demo_function(a: u32) -> u32;
    fn my_demo_function_alias(a: u32) -> u32;
}

mod Foo {
    // No `extern` equals `extern "Rust"`.
    fn my_demo_function(a: u32) -> u32 {
        a
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_success() {
        // The externally imported functions are UNSAFE by default
        // because of untrusted source of other languages. You may
        // wrap them in safe Rust APIs to ease the burden of callers.
        //
        // SAFETY: We know those functions are aliases of a safe
        // Rust function.
        unsafe {
            my_demo_function(123);
            my_demo_function_alias(456);
        }
    }
}
\

please give me some suggetions

This article can help you: https://dev.to/stevepryde/intro-to-rust-modules-3g8k

@AdamBasha not really. This exercise is about using no_mangle and link_name, your are explicitly told to only modify attributes.

Let's consider what the existing code currently does:

The following code tells the compiler that the symbols my_demo_function and my_demo_function_alias are defined elsewhere, but will be Rust functions that each take a single u32 argument and return a u32 result.

extern "Rust" {
    fn my_demo_function(a: u32) -> u32;
    fn my_demo_function_alias(a: u32) -> u32;
}



The following code tells the compiler to define some symbol (the mangled version of Foo::my_demo_function) as a Rust function that takes a single u32 argument and returns it as the u32 result.

mod Foo {
    fn my_demo_function(a: u32) -> u32 {
        a
    }
}




As the instructions say:

your task is to make the testcase able to call themy_demo_functionin
module Foo. themy_demo_function_aliasis an alias formy_demo_function, so the two
line of code in the testcase should call the same function.
You should NOT modify any existing code except for adding two lines of attributes.

You've been told that #[no_mangle] will suppress the default mangling of a function's symbol so that it can be addressed by name; and you've been told that #[link_name = "..."] will modify the actual symbol name that an externally-defined function uses.
Therefore:

 extern "Rust" {
     fn my_demo_function(a: u32) -> u32;
     #[link_name = "my_demo_function"]
     fn my_demo_function_alias(a: u32) -> u32;
 }

 mod Foo {
     // No extern equals extern "Rust".
     #[no_mangle]
     fn my_demo_function(a: u32) -> u32 {
         a
     }
 }
 
See it on the Playground

